# jQueryUI on Laravel Blade

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am implementing jQueryUI to my Laravel app, I want to have a delete confirmation, but I'm failing to implement one. Here is my code:

```
@foreach(array_chunk($items->all(), 3) as $row)
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:40px;">

@foreach ($row as $item)
    <div class="col-md-4">

    <img src="{{$item->img_loc}}">
    <div>
    <strong>Breed: </strong>{{ $item->bname}}<br/>
    <strong>GameFarm: </strong>{{ $item->g_origin}}<br/>
    <strong>Leg Band: </strong>{{ $item->lband}}
    <h3><a href="{{ action('GamefarmsController@edit', $item->id) }}" >Edit</a>|<a id="thelink" href="#">Delete</a></h3>
    </div>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
   <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog(
            {
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                buttons:
                {
                    "Delete": function()
                    {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function()
                    {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to make the program to be redirected to my controller by this code, this carries the $items->id as looped on at the top code like the edit.

```
{{ action('GamefarmsController@delete', $item->id) }}
```

I tried experimenting on this code, but nothing happens.

**EDIT**: Here is the remaining script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#thelink').click(function(){ $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: are you getting the confirmation dialog now, If yes please post the whole jquery code

Comment: yes, wait i'll update it

Comment: what is the function to detect whether user confirmed the delete or not ?

Comment: its the last code i posted on my update

Answer (score 0):

add a `href` as deleting links as below

```
<a class="confirmLink" href="{{ action('GamefarmsController@delete', $item->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

then in `js`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true
    });
  });

  $(".confirmLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // get the url of // href="{{ action('GamefarmsController@delete', $item->id) }}"

    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
       title: "confirmation",
       buttons: {
          "Delete": function () {
              $(this).dialog('close');
              window.location.href = targetUrl; // change browser path to url in delete link
           },
           "Cancel": function () {
              $(this).dialog('close');
              callback(false);
           }
       }
    });

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
  });
</script>
```